# November 2011 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chats (scheduled)

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding Town Hall Chat sessions with the candidates.  These will be opportunities for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I worked with the candidates to find times that allowed the most participation.

---

**There will be *two* town hall chats during the primary phase to accommodate scheduling**.

#### Town Hall Chat #1

The first town hall chat took place Wednesday the 16th at 02:00 UTC (Tuesday the 15th at 21:00 [9pm] EST in the US).

[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=11&day=16&year=2011&hour=2&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

***[Browse the digest of THC #1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112443/november-2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest-1)***

#### Town Hall Chat #2

The second town hall chat took place Wednesday the 16th at 19:00 UTC / 14:00 (2pm) EST.

[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=11&day=16&year=2011&hour=19&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

***[Browse the digest of THC #2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112538/november-2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest-2)***

---

Here are the details so far:

- Town Hall Chats are one-hour events that use our [chat platform](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active).  To join the room directly, [click here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/505/town-hall-chat).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.

Comment: Looking forward to it!

Comment: +1 It'd be sweet if you could broadcast this, with a twitter tag or a live SO thread as its being televised. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Next, can we rally all of the fine programmers we have to build an open source replacement for Doodle? I'll need to eat nine bags of Skittles to make the world right again after using it.

Comment: @TimPost LOL, isn't that Rich Skrenta of blekko.com

Comment: my fingers are still numb from clicking yes or no over 100 times.

Comment: Agreed on Doodle. While I like the distinction between "Yes" and "If I *have* to", I'd like it if it would have defaulted everything to "No" and let me change it (for all I know, that's what it does, but I didn't see it state that anywhere so I answered them all).

Comment: I still stand by my comment [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10575/what-is-a-good-webapp-for-finding-the-best-meeting-time-for-a-group-of-people/13320#13320).  Unfortunately, it's the only one that at least *has* some vital features, and that has to win over bad ui. ):  If there's a better solution, I'm all ears - add it to the webapps question too!  (For most of the other town hall chats, I just ask people to reply to my email with their timezone and their availability and just skip Doodle...but with this many people...)

Comment: @TimPost your comment here seems to indicate you filled out the form, but I only see a comment on Doodle from you, not an actual entry... o:

Comment: @Rebecca I posted 'yes' for the times I'm available, everything else is a 'no'.

Comment: Why am I so nervous about this? :S

Comment: I made two submissions, please delete the first.  Now where do I go get treatment for this RSI..? ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: Me too. *"If I am elected moderator, I'll eliminate three tags! 'Homework', 'subjective', and...umm...the third tag I'd eliminate is the...ummm...."*

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Oh wonderful. I spent a little while shading in all 144 possible blocks, apparently .. in vein :( .. I'll submit it again. Oh the stuff we endure in the name of scheduling.

Comment: @StuThompson You made me nervous, I just went to double check that we didn't have an "`ummmm`" tag.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff could you confirm my submission ? I'm not sure it got saved, so if you could, I would be happy.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: Done, if you could confirm my submission, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Any updates on this? Since the first possible day is tomorrow, it would be helpful to know when we'll be doing this, or at least whether or not it's tomorrow ;)

Comment: @AdamRobinson updated (:

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are only nominations supposed to register, or anyone wanting to participate?

Comment: @Pubby8 anyone is welcome to register!  You'll get a reminder notification if you do, and it lets us see about how many plan to show up.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: Are the maderator nominations encouraged to ask questions of each other, or should the questions only be from those voting on the nominees?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: That was meant to be "moderator nominees" and not "maderator nominations".  If elected moderator one of the first things I'll propose is a way to better edit comments (J/K)

Comment: @casperOne, I have no problems with a candidate asking a question.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: I assume you mean to *other* candidates (*really* don't want to make an assumption here).

Comment: @casperOne sure.  This is meant to be open.  There may even be existing moderators in attendance, so a candidate could ask a question of them.

Comment: I can't make either, sadly.  I have something on at the time of the first meet, and I'm at work during the second.  @Rebecca: Thx for organizing this.