# Using bold or italics within a word in a comment does not work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, markdown

I just tried to comment multiple times on "[November 2011 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat (scheduled)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111863/november-2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-scheduled)".

The intended comment was to be rendered as:

> not "m**a**derator nominations"

But instead, it was rendered as:

```
not "m**a**derator nominations"
```

I also tried the following variants, with no effect (rendered as you see here):

```
not "m*a*derator nominations"
not 'm**a**derator nominations'
not 'm*a*derator nominations'
```

Note there were other posts about similar behavior, but they were either marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or were specific to placement of the bold/italics in relation to the quotes (usually right before/after them).

Comment: not "m**a**derator nominations"  
not "m*a*derator nominations"  
not 'm**a**derator nominations'  
not 'm*a*derator nominations'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the quote signs. Nor with comments, for that matter; as you observed when posting your question, it's not working in regular post Markdown either -- just that here, you have the HTML tag workaround.

As for the reasons that this isn't working (which is indeed intentional), I refer you to [Three Markdown Gotchas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/) (in particular, point 1) and its follow-up [Markdown, One Year Later](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/markdown-one-year-later/).

Comment: Is there a workaround for this, if I need to, say, bold a single letter of a word, or bold the first word of an italicized phrase in a comment? _**First** words of italicized phrases seem "unboldable", yet words in the **middle** of a phrase turn to bold just fine_. As someone who spends a lot of time on the language boards, this "gotcha" gets me rather often. (Typed as: `_**First** words of italicized phrases seem "unboldable", yet words in the **middle** of a phrase turn to bold just fine_.`)

Comment: not "m**a**derator nominations"  If this was "indeed intentional" then someone changed the intent, because it is now working. I would suggest changing this from [meta-tag:status-bydesign] to [meta-tag:status-completed] Or am I missing something?